# Measure size/length of singly linked list in Java?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, size

I need help making the `int size();` method for a singly linked list in Java.

This is what I have so far, but it does not return the correct size of the list.

```
public int size()
{
    int size = 0;
    Node CurrNode = head;
    while(CurrNode.next != null)
    {
        CurrNode = CurrNode.next;
        size++;     
    }
    return size;
}
```

Can someone help me implement this method in Java?

Comment: looks like a school example - for real world code you would want to use one of the numerous List implementations in the standard library

Comment: Also: The java convention is that variable names start with lower case letter, so you should probably rename `CurrNode` into `currNode`. It will make fellow java coders much more fond with your code (My first thought for example was "Why is he accessing a static variable in the class `CurrNode`", and I needed a second read to see it is not the case)

Answer (score 10):

The biggest improvement you can make is to use Java Coding Convension and use camelCase local variables.

You can write it like this.

```
public int size() {
   int size = 0;
   for(Node n = head; n.next != null; n = n.next)
       size++;     
   return size;
}
```

as you are re-writing a commonly used class in Java, I suggest you have a look at how it is done there if you want a better way of doing things.

From [LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

```
/**
 * Returns the number of elements in this list.
 *
 * @return the number of elements in this list
 */
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

As you can see, when an element is added size is incremented and when an element is removed it id decremented saving you having to traverse the list to get the size.

Comment: for(Node n = head; n.next != null; n = n.next)
       size++; 
   this always give the number of actual element in list with one short

Comment: @daskinder this code assumes that the `head` is not an entry just the start of the linked list as LinkedList does.  if you want this to be a node you need to check whether it is `null` and add one.

Comment: Where does `.next` come from? I don't see that it is a part of the `Node` class, and there is no variable declaration.

Comment: @NoniA. The `.next` is in the sample code from the OP. I assumed from the code provided that there is a field called `next`

Comment: Thanks Peter. I was curious because I found this use of `.next` in the book Cracking the Coding Interview, and it was a variable of type `Node`. That's probably what it was in the OP's code too.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to have variable that tracks the size initialised at 0. Then each time you add a node it's just size++, or size-- when you remove a node. You size() method then just has to return this variable without traversing the list.

Comment: oh I see, the homework sort of limited that by saying this would work for an input linked list, and I would have to at least measure that once before I can do a size++/-- for add/delete. I'll have to try that separately to get my coding syntax down.

Comment: if the input linkedlist is the same class as the one you are adding it to, then it will still work. e.g. addList(LinkedList otherList) { addLast(otherList.head); this.size += otherList.size(); }

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the list to your method and check currNode!= null :

```
public static int size(Node currNode){
    int count = 0;
    while (currNode!= null){
        count++;
        currNode=currNode.getNext();
    }
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way to calculate the length is by checking whether the currentNode!=null and keep the currentNode incrementing .

We can use while or a for loop to implement this.

Below is an example where for loop is used.

```
public int getLength(){
    ListNode temp = head;
    for(temp = head; temp!=null; temp=temp.getNextNode()){

        length++;
    }
    return length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a simple while loop to determine how many nodes there are in the linked list to do that I always create a new current variable to track where am I in the list.

```
public int addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1) {
    int l1Len = 0;
    ListNode current = l1;

    while(current != null)
    {
        current = current.next;
        l1Len = l1Len + 1;
    }

    return l1Len;
}
```