# How to return the number of elements in a linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, element

I need to implement the size() function so that it will count the number of elements in a list.

I cannot use a count variable. Should work (given our 'top' node and the constructors [default] setup). I know i have to use a loop but i don't know how to reference indices like i do with arrays.

```
     public class DropOutStack<T> implements StackADT<T> {
      private int max;
      private LinearNode<T> top;

     public DropOutStack(){
      max = 10;
      top = null;
     }

     public DropOutStack(int capacity){
      setMaxSize(capacity);
     }

     public DropOutStack(T element){
      LinearNode<T> temp = newLinearNode(element);
      temp.setNext(top);
      top = temp;
      max = 10;
      }

     public DropOutStack(T element, int capacity){
      LinearNode<T> temp = newLinearNode(element);
      temp.setNext(top);
      top = temp;
      setMaxSize(capacity);
      }

     public int size(){

      }

     public boolean isEmpty(){
      if(top == null) return true;
       return false; 
      }
}
```

DropOutStack list = new DropOutStack("T",4);

System.out.print(list.size());

Should print 1. Since only "T" has been added.

Adding a screenshot of the composition class. I think I have to use a method from there. Interface just declares the push pop peek isempty functions. No code. Not needed for the size() function I believe. This is my first programming class so I hope I gave everything needed to solve this. Please help [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTqBL.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Measure size/length of singly linked list in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12617021/measure-size-length-of-singly-linked-list-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that will count the elements:

```
ToIntFunction<LinearNode<T>> counter = (node) -> {
  int count = 0;
  while( node != null ) {
    count++;
    node = node.getNext();
  }
  return( count );
};
```

…applied in the DropOutStack class size() function:

```
public int size() {
  return( counter.applyAsInt( top ) );
}
```